# Bash Script: result of xargs assigned to variable loses all but one item

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm running a bash script that greps through files to identify tests, then it should output the results to a string and store in a variable. When the command is run on its own it echoes out all the files in a single line correctly, but when I try to assign the results to a variable, only one is shown.

This works as expected and will show a complete list of the files expected.

```
grep -Erli ' @IsTest| testmethod' './build/source/classes' | sed 's#.*/## ; s#.cls##' | xargs echo
```

However, when I do this the result of the echo is that only one file is listed in the `TESTS` variable

```
TESTS=($(grep -Erli ' @IsTest| testmethod' './build/source/classes' | sed 's#.*/## ; s#.cls##' | xargs echo))
echo $TESTS
```

Is there something about putting this in a variable assignment expression that is a problem? It seems to be an issue of the whitespace between each item. If I add  `| tr ' ' ','` to the end so it replaces whitespace with commas everything is listed, but that's not a solution I can use for this. I need a whitespace separated list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TESTS=( ... )` is creating an *array* of entries.

`echo $TESTS` is the same as `echo ${TESTS[0]}`, ie, display the 1st entry in the array.

To display the entire contents of the array try `echo "${TESTS[@]}"` or `typeset -p TESTS`.

Consider:

```
$ TESTS=( a b c )

$ echo "$TESTS"
a

$ echo "${TESTS[0]}"
a

$ echo "${TESTS[@]}"
a b c

$ typeset -p TESTS
declare -a TESTS=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")
```

Comment: Is this something unique to running from within a .sh file? When I set the variable the same way from the command line, and then simply `echo $TESTS` I get the full results. This only seems to happen when I do this from within a .sh file.

Comment: the behavior you're describing sounds like you may be using a different shell for a) the command line vs b) the script; it would help if you updated the questoin with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with details about command line vs script (to include the shell being used for command line vs script); it's also possible that you're not setting the variable the same way, eg, `TESTS=$(grep ... )` is not the same as `TESTS=( $(grep ...) )`; without a reproducible example I'm just *guessing* at what the issue may be ...

Comment: That would be it. I didn't even consider. The script is `#!/bin/sh`, and my command line is zsh. So, yeah, they don't match. Either way, adding the `[@]` fixes my issue. Thanks!